M2.3: fotorama smooth scroll for mobile
I have a problem with the scroll of the gallery's navigation on mobile. On mobile, I put to also have thumbnails
<var name="breakpoints">
            <var name="mobile">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">767px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="options">
                        <var name="nav">thumbs</var>
                        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>

The problem is that when I scroll in the nav, the scroll is not smoothly at all and it scroll only around 20-30px. Does anyone have a solution to this? Thank you!

I made something that look like this:
On line 1775(for me), in fotorama.js, we got jQuery.Fotorama = function ($fotorama, opts)
and there we have navShaftTouchTail = moveOnTouch, inside onEnd function  in the else if (result.pos !== result.newPos) I added:
const pos = result.newPos < result.pos ? result.newPos - 75 : result.newPos + 75; and I changed slide function parameters like this
slide($navShaft, {
                        time: result.time,
                        pos: pos,
                        overPos: result.overPos,
                        direction: opts.navdir,
                        onEnd: onEnd
                    });

The final result looks like:
onEnd: function (result) {

                function onEnd() {
                    slideNavShaft.l = result.newPos;
                    releaseAutoplay();
                    changeAutoplay();
                    thumbsDraw(result.newPos, true);
                    thumbArrUpdate();
                }

                if (!result.moved) {
                    var target = result.$target.closest('.' + navFrameClass, $navShaft)[0];
                    target && onNavFrameClick.call(target, result.startEvent);
                } else if (result.pos !== result.newPos) {
                    pausedAutoplayFLAG = true;
                    const pos = result.newPos < result.pos ? result.newPos - 75 : result.newPos + 75;
                    slide($navShaft, {
                        time: result.time,
                        pos: pos,
                        overPos: result.overPos,
                        direction: opts.navdir,
                        onEnd: onEnd
                    });
                    thumbsDraw(result.newPos);
                    o_shadows && setShadow($nav, findShadowEdge(result.newPos, navShaftTouchTail.min, navShaftTouchTail.max, result.dir));
                } else {
                    onEnd();
                }
            },

